# Create intervals from set of dates dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you receive lists of dates using ajax, how can you dynamically create date intervalls from it? Lets say for example your list is:

```
var arrdates=['01/02/2014','06/05/2014','24/09/2014','05/06/2018','26/09/2019','27/09/2019','28/12/2019'];
```

And you would want a result that looks like this:

```
console.log("Date intervals are 01/02/2014-24/09/2014 and 05/06/2018 and 26/09/2019-28/12/2019");
```

Is something like this even possible?

Comment: Your Question is not clear , can you add some details? do you wanna set interval for 7 months? am i right?

Comment: @AmirDoreh detect the beginning and ending date intervals in a list of dates that are also ordered. Ive specified it using an example, the console log shows what i mean. thanks

Comment: what do you need exactly? you will take the millisecond different of given data and pass it into your `setInterval()` . which part do you get problem on?

Comment: @AmirDoreh This has nothing to do with setInterval(). if you look at the array you will see at index 0 the beginning of date 2014 in the array is 01/02/2014 and its ending date is at index 3 which is 24/09/2014. These dates obviosuly changes as i make calls from api. I dont know how to explain better than this!

Comment: It should do the same then with rest of dates in the array. for ex 2018 is same beginning and ending but its different for 2019

Comment: So do you only want to group them in intervals if the are the same year?

Comment: @Gbr22 yes, the beginning of the year in list and the end of same year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you could do it.

```js
var arrdates=['01/02/2014','06/05/2014','24/09/2014','05/06/2018','26/09/2019','27/09/2019','28/12/2019'];
let yearsMap = new Map();
arrdates.forEach(e=>{
  let y = (new Date(e.split("/").reverse().join("-")/*convert to ISO date string*/)).getFullYear();
  let current = yearsMap.get(y);
  yearsMap.set(y, current ? [...current,e] : [e]);
})
let years = [...yearsMap.values()].map(e=>e.join("-")); //might want to sort the dates before joining
console.log(years);
```

Comment: this is printing the exakt same array! What i meant more is that the date that is 06/05/2014 and any other that is in between the start of year which in array is 01/02/2014 and end of it 24/09/2014, should be removed. so in first line it should be 01/02/2014-24/09/2014. This is not simply as removing secound index because the range is different everytime i get dates from api

Comment: If you could make an array of all dates in same year i could go and extract first and last index into new arrays!

Comment: I went through your code fully and changed it and created the structure i wanted. thanks i accepted it as an answer

Comment: Glad I could help! :-)